# SSL support for libcurl

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

At the beginning I want to tell you that I download libcurl from main site (i.e http://curl.haxx.se/download.html )
And version called:

**Win64 2000/XP x86_64 zip  7.40.0  binary  SSL     SSH     Edward LoPinto**

**I'm working on MSVC 2013 ultimate x64**

Okey, this package seems to have SSL support (it contains ssl libs )

Program compiling fine, but when i try to run some https site I have got:

> Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl.

I think that it is disabled (because this package contains ssl support). 
Question is:

**How to enable SSL support in libcurl ?**

---

I solve my problem by compiling libcurl on my own hand.

It may help other people:

MSVC 2013 - 64 bit - 7.41.0 + OPENSSL
[download](https://mega.co.nz/#!0ws3VArI!sPON2xyl_X6zgupR0m_GM3Lufs5gSVNd7BtUTYcm3y4)

[scan](https://www.virustotal.com/pl/file/b44738d9a2ae69a0bba4f0b96e926b5bbe772fd67b6b845cbdaad2dcb6e7d07c/analysis/1426428765/)

Comment: What exact command gives that error? (Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884669/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl ?)

Comment: @AlanStokes I solve my problem - because of compiling libcurl from the beginning. Packages I uploaded there - may help the others :)

MSVC 2013 - 64 bit - 7.41.0 + OPENSSL
[download](https://mega.co.nz/#!0ws3VArI!sPON2xyl_X6zgupR0m_GM3Lufs5gSVNd7BtUTYcm3y4)

[scan](https://www.virustotal.com/pl/file/b44738d9a2ae69a0bba4f0b96e926b5bbe772fd67b6b845cbdaad2dcb6e7d07c/analysis/1426428765/)