# curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl [Ubuntu]

Tags: ruby, ssl, curl, ubuntu-14.04

while i'm installing ruby on `Ubuntu 14.04` using steps specified in `rvm.io` I got these error which is related to `curl`.
After writing this `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

> curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

And I also tried this command `./configure --with-ssl` and it's not working.
I have xampp installed in my pc.
and this solution [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884669/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl) is showing for windows not for Ubuntu.
suggested solution is not working
Please help :) thanks in advance.

Comment: @KirillZhukov it seems duplicate but that solutions are not working for me so i again ask. :)

Comment: and i already specified what i tried.