# Protocol Https not supported or disabled in curl

Tags: curl

Am getting this error even though when i do

```
curl -V
```

https is listed as one of the protocol.

Below is the curl command I input into shell:

```
curl -u {'username-key'} -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -X POST -d '{"dialog_node":"Animals"}' 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/{my workspace id}/dialog_nodes/LivingThings?version=2018-07-10'
```

This is a command to change the name of a dialog node inside IBM Watson. Attached the API for reference,

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#update-dialog-node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can actually reproduce this with your curl command:

> curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

The `'` before `https` made me suspicious so I tried without the quotes around the URL:

```
curl -u {'username-key'} -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -X POST -d '{"dialog_node":"Animals"}' https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/{my workspace id}/dialog_nodes/LivingThings?version=2018-07-10
```

And this works for me.

The double-quotes of the error message make this barely recognizable, it actually says:

> *Protocol `'https` not supported*

It interprets the escaping (single-)quotes as part of the URL/protocol.

On Windows cmd it is a known behaviour that quoting only works with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76076172/3233722) ?

Ref: "*curl : (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl*"