# Get raw file from repository with curl

Tags: git, curl

I'm using code from gitlab docs for getting xmlfile from repository:

```
curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: MYTOKEN' 'https://gitlab.com/semborfo/tester/raw/COMMIT_HASH/PoliqonSysem.xml'
```

But then getting

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: MYTOKEN' 
curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Can u help me with this problem? i have already spent 4 hours for this

Comment: I guess it is a _gitlab_ problem, not a _git_ problem, isn't it?

Comment: It looks like it could be a problem with the quoting of the arguments in the shell.

`Could not resolve host: MYTOKEN` seems to indicate that it's splitting the header at space after the colon. Which shell are you using, or how are you calling curl?

Comment: i'm using it from CMD. u were right i deleted space, and now there is only one problem left, with libcurl

Comment: It might be the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24232441/852893

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl : (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884669/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: aabbcc" https://sample.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/5295/repository/files/lib%2Freference%2Fmaven%2Fsettings%2Exml/raw?ref=master

Where `aabbcc` is your private access token, it has **an espace** before `aabbcc`.
This command will get content of settings.xml which is in:

```
myProject(project ID is 5295, branch master)
    -src
    -lib
       |-reference
             |-maven
                 |-settings.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

> `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: MYTOKEN'`

Seems like there is a trailing space, should be `PRIVATE_TOKEN:MY_TOKEN`

> `curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Sometimes single quote `'` are not really liked, try using `"`