# Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl ubuntu python

Tags: python, curl, github, cmake, openssl

I am trying to run a repository from github in ubuntu18.
after running

```
python3 setup.py develop --user
```

I got the error

```
CMake Error at libmypaint-stamp/download-libmypaint.cmake:159 (message):
  Each download failed!

    error: downloading 'https://github.com/mypaint/libmypaint/releases/download/v1.3.0/libmypaint-1.3.0.tar.xz' failed
         status_code: 1
         status_string: "Unsupported protocol"
         log:
         --- LOG BEGIN ---
         Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

  Closing connection -1



         --- LOG END ---
```

I've seen other related topics , but didn't get my answer .

and this is the result of running `curl --version` :

```
curl 7.65.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.65.3 OpenSSL/1.1.1
Release-Date: 2019-07-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

any help ? 
Regards

Comment: "I've seen other related topics , but didn't get my answer." - Then you probably want to describe in the question post **what** (which answers on related topics) **have you tried**. E.g. what is an output of `curl --version` (from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523168/3440745)).

Comment: tnx , i've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find what causes the problem . but I downloaded the repository manually and edited the CMakeList.txt to use the local file URL.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, cmake is not using curl when making. I re-install my cmake like this:

```
git clone -b v3.10.2 https://cmake.org/cmake.git cmake
cd cmake
./bootstrap --system-curl
make
sudo make install
```

When it comes into 'Could NOT find ZLIB', just download zlib in http://www.zlib.net/fossils/, make and install zlib. Then re-install cmake.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. My issue is resolved by upgrading CMake version to 3.25.